# トラッキングコードをアップロードの方法

Tags: html

トラッキングコードをHTMLにタグずけしたいのですが、やり方が解りません？
HTMLにアップロード？のやり方も解りません？

素人に解る説明をお願いしたいです。

Answer (score 1):

やりたい内容によりますが、アクセス数解析(集計目的)であればGoogle Analytics が良いと思います。アカウントの取得方法は下記のリンクを辿って調べて下さい。

https://www.google.com/intl/ja_jp/analytics/

サイトを登録した後、[管理][トラッキング情報][トラッキングコード]を選択するとscriptタグとjavascriptがテキストボックスに表示されるのでそれを自分のサイトのHTMLのどこかに貼りつけます。出来ればbodyタグ内の直後が良いです。

またそうではなく、アクセスのあった相手のIPアドレスを記録したいという事であれば、ウェブサーバのアクセスログを見るのが良いと思います。

おそらくこのサイト登録の最初に行うHTMLファイルのアップロードですが、サイトの直下に置く必要があります。サイトへファイルを置く手法はさまざまでFTPによる物、管理コンソールからアップロードなど多岐に渡る為、サービスを使っているのかそれとも自分のサーバなのかを教えて頂けると追記出来ます。